# how did facebook messenger switch between activities

Tags: android, facebook

how can facebook hide current activity and show another activity here in chathead 
when choose another one to talk with him its hide current popup floating activity and show the other one activity

[image]

i don't think its start new activity because i write some message on current activity in the `editText` without send it and when choose another one to talk with him its hide current activity and when i back open it the text i write it it's still there thats mean it's dosen't start new activity when switch to other conversation

iam try to make something like facebook chathead but i have problem i switch between floating activities

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are using Fragments and Floating Action Buttons.

Also just for your information, unless you specifically call finish() on an activity, it will only get stopped when the new activity is started. When you return, it will go back to onResume() state.

Please look into activity life cycle and Fragment Life cycle to know about these things more clearly. The faster you have a clear idea about these, the easier it will be in the long run

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

NOTE: **When it is on the home screen, It is an window running on top of the background service with a floating window , while inside the app it is a Fragment.**

see tutorial: http://androidsrc.net/facebook-chat-like-floating-chat-heads/

Comment: NOTE: the activity can get garbage collected even when no finish is called. This only happens when android gc decides to do so though.. mostly in low memory situations

Comment: thanks for this awesome answer but did u have an example or tutorial talk about Floating Action Buttons. with Fragments

Comment: please are sure its Fragments i think its floating activities

Comment: you can google around and learn fragments first-> Then create a custom DialogFragment and give it your own layout which looks like the Fb layout. Now use a FAB either from some library on github or android support. onClick() start your fragment and add to backstack. onClick() again, popBackStack() to remove the fragment. similarly for other buttons

Comment: fragments  must be inside activity that's what i know so how can i use fragments without activity and also not inside screen

Comment: Can't be sure a 100% am sure about 99% , most likely it's a fragment. Makes more sense if it is because the chat head can be switched on and off multiple times. An activity here would be more costly than a fragment.

Comment: i make a cool chathead app but have problem on switch between activities
see update question